# how to play video with augmented reality in android

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, augmented-reality

i found many AR tutorial just show 3D object when detect a pattern, i need some advice to make application that can play video with AR application using android camera?

Answer (score 0):

To play video on marker detection in Augmented Reality you should use the   https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk> "Vuforial SDK" it has sample named as video play that will help you to play video on marker

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is to use the [Creator](http://dev.metaio.com/creator/getting-started/). Load a tracking image and then drag and drop the video onto the tracking image. You can then launch to iOS or Android. No coding needed.

If you want to code, here's a [tutorial](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/content-types/) with sample codes, tracking pattern, and sample video files using the Metaio SDK.